# AWS CDK java Lambda Function from an Docker Image, Runtime Error

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, jsii

I use AWS CDK to build a lambda function from an image.

```
  //This build the docker image
  AssetCode code = Code.fromDockerBuild(file.toAbsolutePath().toString(),
        DockerBuildAssetOptions.builder()
             .imagePath("/var/task")
             .outputPath(file.toAbsolutePath().toString() + "/cdk.out" )
             .platform("linux/amd64")
             .build()
   );

   Function lambda = Function.Builder.create(stack, LAMBDA_FUNCTION_ID)
          .runtime(Runtime.FROM_IMAGE)
          .description("My Description ")
          .role(lambdaRole)
          .code(code)
          .handler("com.mycompany.myproject.MyHandler")
          .memorySize(1024)
          .environment(env)
          .logRetention(ONE_WEEK)
          .timeout(Duration.seconds(60))
          .events(List.of(source))
          .build();
```

The image builds successfully but when the function builds, I get this error.

`Exception in thread "main" software.amazon.jsii.JsiiError: runtime must be 'Runtime.FROM_IMAGE' when using image asset for Lambda function Error: runtime must be 'Runtime.FROM_IMAGE' when using image asset for Lambda function`

AWS CDK uses jsii, here is a snippet of the request going from the Java code to the JSII lib.

```
{
    "fqn": "aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.Function",
    "args": [{
        "$jsii.byref": "aws-cdk-lib.Stack@10001"
    }, "opd-bmwfd-fdvsp-int-dbpersists-lambda", {
        "$jsii.struct": {
            "fqn": "aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.FunctionProps",
            "data": {
                "code": {
                    "$jsii.byref": "aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.AssetCode@10007"
                },
                "handler": "com.bmw.fleetdata.DBPersistsHandler",
                "runtime": {
                    "$jsii.byref": "aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.Runtime@10035"
                },
```

Where `aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.Runtime@10035` points to class Object Runtime.FROM_IMAGE in the jvm.
So it seem that the AWS CDK is at fault, but I cannot find any other leads.

1. Is my Function create method correct?
2. Is this a known issue, I cannot find anything on issue log?

**Update:**
I create the same stack, using only typescript and got the same error.
So it must be CDK causing the issue.

```
const code = Code.fromDockerBuild(path,  {imagePath: '/var/task', outputPath: path})

const lambda = new Function(this, this.getVariable('LAMBDA_FUNCTION_ID', fdEnv),  {
      code: code,
      handler: "com.mycompany.myproject.MyHandler",
      runtime: Runtime.FROM_IMAGE,
      description: '',
      role: lambdaRole,
      memorySize: 1024,
      environment: fdEnv.value,
      logRetention: RetentionDays.ONE_WEEK,
      timeout: Duration.seconds(60),
      events: [eventSource]
    })
```

The error

```
Error: runtime must be `Runtime.FROM_IMAGE` when using image asset for Lambda function
```

Comment: What's your CDK version?

Comment: software.amazon.awscdk:aws-cdk-lib:2.66.0

Comment: Is this the only lambda function in your app?

Comment: Yes, only one function, connecting to a queue  and a rds cluster proxy.